# Can you use "had" for the present tense?

Tags: tense, past-tense, present-tense

> Your suggested edit is pending review.
>
> **Editor Stats**
>
> - CJ Dennis had 2 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected

Is "had" correct in that sentence? It is the number I have right now, and it increases when I get more approved edits and go back to that page. Shouldn't it say:

> - CJ Dennis **has** 2 edit suggestions approved, and 0 edit suggestions rejected

Comment: Yeah I thought this [looked familiar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/337553/323179).

Comment: I think it's fine. *"CJ Dennis had [gotten] 2 of their edit suggestions approved by the reviewers"*. It is grammatical. But that does not mean it can't be written as "CJ Dennis has 2 approved edit suggestions".

Comment: No, you can't use *had* for the present tense. Nor is this sentence describing anything in the present. It's describing events that took place in the past. If it were to be the present tense, then *approved* and *rejected* would be used as adjectives, not as a verbs: *CJ Dennis has 2 approved edit suggestions, and 0 rejected edit suggestions.*

Answer (score 1):

Had isn't in present tense in that sentence. A suggestion being approved is an event that happened in the past. An edit suggestion isn't a thing that you own or accumulate.

It's similar to saying "I ate 2 apples". If you eat another apple you can say "I ate 3 apples". But "ate" is still past tense, because it happened in the past.

Comment: I had (gave birth to) three children. Why is it grammatically incorrect to say that I **have** three children now? (It isn't.) If I ate three apples (and those were all the apples I had), I have no apples now. If I don't have 2 edit suggestions approved now, what happened to them? Of course an edit suggestion is something you can "own" or accumulate. I made **my** edit suggestion before you made **yours**. "Have" implies _association_, not ownership, as does what is traditionally called genitive.

Comment: When you say you "had" 3 children, you are referring to the event of their birth. (unless they are dead, and you're speaking in past tense). When you talk about "having" children now you're talking about them being alive/in your life. They are different sentences with different meanings. You *could* say "has edit suggestions" if you are thinking about them as an ongoing thing you accumulate, but that doesn't make "had 2 edit suggestions approved" wrong. It's a different sentence with a different meaning.

Comment: Also I think "has" would be more correct if the sentence was "CJ Dennis has 2 approved edit suggestions", where "approved" is an adjective describing "edit suggestions". But in the original sentence "approved" is a verb -- an action you take with an "edit suggestion", referring to an event in the past.

Comment: You are correct that "approved" is a verb (a past participle). It can't be replaced by any adjective, e.g. "green" doesn't work. However, the sentence is passive: "CJ Dennis had 2 edit suggestions approved by other users". The equivalent active sentence is "Other users had approved 2 of CJ Dennis' edit suggestions". Had? Before what? Better is "Other users have approved 2 of CJ Dennis' edit suggestions", which makes the original passive sentence "CJ Dennis has 2 edit suggestions approved" to make it true in the present, not just the past and maybe the present.